# ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: azure, pyodbc, unixodbc

I tried to connect to SQL server using OBDC. It works perfectly locally and the docker running locally on the docker desktop. However, it throws out an error when I try to connect from the web app for the container in Azure.

ERROR:root:Error message: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
ERROR:root:Error type: OperationalError

```
    connect_string = f"DRIVER={DATABASE_DRIVER};"
    connect_string += f"SERVER={DATABASE_PROTOCOL}:{DATABASE_SERVER},"
    connect_string += f"{DATABASE_PORT};"
    connect_string += f"DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};"
    connect_string += f"UID={DATABASE_USER};"
    connect_string += f"PWD={DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    

    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
```

I have tried:

- Ensured the SQL Server is reachable.
- Verified login credentials are correct
- Firewall is not blocking connection is available for the IP address
- Increased the login timeout value

I have also tried other answers in Stack overflow but I am still not able to connect to the server.

Comment: Did you allow the IP address of your Web app to the SQL Server?

Comment: It worked after allowing IP address of Web app to SQL Server. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried the steps below:-

```py
import  pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};''SERVER=tcp:sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;''DATABASE=<DATABASE>; UID=siliconserver;PWD=<Password>;')

#conn.commit()

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('Select * FROM StudentReviews')

#conn.commit()

for  i  in  cursor:

print(i)

cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

Output:-

[image]

When I mis-spelled the SQL Server name in the connection string, I got the same error code as yours, Also, If you do not allow the IP address of your Web app in your SQL server networking , the connection times out. Refer below:-

[image]

Make sure you add your Azure Web app or Containers App IP address in the SQL Server Networking tab like below:-

[image]

You can find the IP address of your Web app and Container App like below:-

[image]

[image]